# Laravel - updateOrCreate() - Integrity constraint violation

Tags: laravel

When using updateOrCreate(), I'm getting the following error:

`Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8acda4a86b26d8dc016b3801b87236b0' for key 'uuid'`

My understanding is that when the unique key already exists in the table, it won't try and insert but instead will update that row so why am I getting this error?

The column uuid is set to unique in my MySQL database.

the column json is a JSON column and is set to NOT NULL.

Here's my code:

```
TransactionJSON::updateOrCreate(
   ['uuid' => $json->payload->id],
   ['json' => $json_merge]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case,

updateorcreate or firstorcreate not check trashed data..

use withTrashed() :

```
TransactionJSON::withTrashed()->updateOrCreate(
  ["uuid" => $json->payload->id],
  ["json" => $json_merge]
);
```

Comment: I just got into this issue and this fixed my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your model `TransactionJSON`, you should set `uuid` as primary key.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
```

that's how laravel will update table by `uuid` otherwise laravel will find entry by `id` ( default primaryKey ) if `id` is not present than it will create one. Learn more https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent

Comment: Even if I already have a primary key column? I have an auto increment column named id as the primary key.